# PDF4NET fails to send file to Printer however is able to created PDF documents

Tags: pdf, printing

I am finding on the fly PDF4NET is not sending files to the printer queue, with the queue paused no file ever reaches it and have tried various printer queues. If I create a pdf document using PDF4NET the file is created and saved as a pdf document, that pdf document I can then manually send to the printer queue and it prints.

Hopefully @iPDFdev see's this question I I see from his activity log he is experienced in this area.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

As @KJ mentioned, PDF4NET cannot print PDF files.

If you can post a sample code fragment that shows what you try to accomplish, maybe I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have to answer that as of today programmable printing is not possible.

From [https://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/faq.htm#:~:text=Can%20PDF4NET%20be%20used%20as%20a%20printer%20driver%3F](https://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/faq.htm#:%7E:text=Can%20PDF4NET%20be%20used%20as%20a%20printer%20driver%3F)

> **Can PDF4NET be used as a printer driver?**
> PDF4NET library can not be used as a printer driver for creating pdf files from Windows applications. It is a .NET class library used from any .NET language to create pdf files from code.

> **Can PDF4NET print existing pdf files to an installed printer?**
> PDF4NET library can not print existing pdf files to a printer, it can only create pdf files from code.

Comment: Hi I am using HP drivers and Kyocera drivers with Windows Print Management queues, the file does not reach the printer. If I click print preview then print to queue the file DOES reach the printer queue as a PDF document.